# How to supply menu images for both 38mm and 42mm on WatchOS?

Tags: apple-watch, xcasset, watchos

I have downloaded templates from Apple's site for preparing icons for Menu Items on WatchOS apps.

I see that there are 2 different templates, for 38mm and 42mm versions.

I didn't understand how I should save them to support both sizes simultaneously. I tried `Assets.xcassets` but there is nothing there related to 38mm and 42mm there.

As this is not something related to `retina` I cannot add `@2x` etc.. to the end of the image's filename.

So how to do that?